# Local push notifications do not appear on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I spent a lot of time testing notifications and I can't make them appear on my Apple Watch. I can receive notifications from other apps - my watch is paired, Do Not Disturbe is disabled. Local push notifications appear on my iPhone but not on the Apple Watch. iPhone screen is locked when notification arrives.

I am doing following:
1. Asking permission
2. Scheduling notification

```
+ (void)requestPermission {

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *smallCupAction = [UIMutableUserNotificationAction new];
    smallCupAction.title = NSLocalizedString(@"250 mL", @"Notification button");
    smallCupAction.identifier = @"add small";
    smallCupAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    smallCupAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *mediumCupAction = [UIMutableUserNotificationAction new];
    mediumCupAction.title = NSLocalizedString(@"350 mL", @"Notification button");
    mediumCupAction.identifier = @"add medium";
    mediumCupAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    mediumCupAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *largeCupAction = [UIMutableUserNotificationAction new];
    largeCupAction.title = NSLocalizedString(@"500 mL", @"Notification button");
    largeCupAction.identifier = @"add large";
    largeCupAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
    largeCupAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *waterReminderCategoryDefault = [UIMutableUserNotificationCategory new];
    [waterReminderCategoryDefault setActions:@[smallCupAction, mediumCupAction, largeCupAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    waterReminderCategoryDefault.identifier = @"water reminder default";

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects: waterReminderCategoryDefault, nil];

    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationType) (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
}

+ (void)scheduleNotificationWithGender:(NSNumber *)gender date:(NSDate *)date {

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = date;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = // localized text
    localNotif.alertAction = // localized text
    localNotif.alertTitle = // localized text

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.category = @"water reminder default";

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:gender, kGenderKey, nil];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

[image: Screenshot of iPhone Lock Screen with the notification. Notifications has 2 actions]

Comment: its work on iphone you mean ?

Comment: @balkaransingh yes

Comment: Is the app installed on the watch? Do you have UI for the notifications?

Comment: @jrturton yes, I have app on the watch. Shouldn't be related. I tried another branch without Apple Watch targets and it is the same - notifications appear only on the iPhone. I do have storyboard file for notifications. Notifications should appear on Apple Watch anyway, notifications do not require Apple Watch app to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by enabling notifications in the Watch app:

1. Open the Watch app on your iPhone, tap the My Watch tab, then tap Notifications.
2. Tap an app.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204791